# Why does my jQuery click handler appear to run multiple times for some of its targets?

Tags: jquery, onclick

I apply:

```
$(".newContentLink").click(function() {
    $("#test").append("1");
});
```

On this:

```
<span id="contents">
<input class="newContentLink" type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="CREATE A NEW CONTENT"/>
<span id="content1" class="content study">
</span>
<input class="newContentLink" type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="CREATE A NEW CONTENT"/>
<span id="content3" class="content study">
</span>
<input class="newContentLink" type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="CREATE A NEW CONTENT"/>
<span id="content4" class="content category">
</span>
<input class="newContentLink" type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="CREATE A NEW CONTENT"/>
</span>
```

How come
when I click on the first 2 buttons it adds 111,
the next button adds 11,
and the last one adds 1?

Comment: try apending a "<p></p>" instead of just "1",

Comment: Where is #test? Maybe it's something with that code

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unable to replicate.  I suspect that you're misrepresenting — oversimplifying, mostly — your situation.  To be precise, I believe you're dynamically adding those inputs, and calling `$(".newContentLink").click(...)` each time — which, naturally, keeps applying additional copies of the click handler to each `.newContentLink` in the page.

So the most recent input you've created has one copy of the click handler and appends one `1`.  The second most recent has two copies and appends `11`.  The third has three and appends `111`, etc.

To prevent this, apply the click handler to your newly created DOM element, not `$(".newContentLink")` (which always means *every* `.newContentLink`).

Comment: Yup, it's almost definitely the `click` handler being added again and again.

Comment: Or use the .live() method to dynamically add event

Answer (score 7):

or you can unbind the click event each time you add a new element

```
$('.newContentLink').unbind('click');

$(".newContentLink").click(function() {
    $("#test").append("1");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

As [chaos says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178141/what-is-the-problem-with-this-jquery-code/1178189#1178189), you're probably calling `click()` each time you add one, and they're accumulating.

If you're adding these items to the document dynamically, and need to make sure this function is added to every one you add, how about using live?

```
$('#contents').on('click', '.newContentLink', function() {
    $("#test").append("1");
});
```

This will make sure the rule is dynamically applied once to any qualifying class in the document.

Comment: I believe the syntax should be .live( 'click', function () {

Comment: That code didn't work for me. I checked the docs, and this did:
$(".newContentLink").live("click", function(){ $("#test").append("1"); });

Comment: I confess, I didn't check the syntax before posting.

Comment: Not only is the syntax wrong (perhaps edit it...?), live() is depreciated in favor of on().

Answer (score 3):

To make sure the function only execute once on one click event
you may use $(".newContentLink").one();

```
$(".newContentLink").one(function() {
    $("#test").append("1");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick. I was not adding elements but selecting multiple rows from a table so everytime I was selecting another item, click event was being added and accumulated.

Answer (score 2):

Not a jQuery bug - **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/axixi)**

There must be a problem with something else in your code. Where is the element with `id="test"` in your markup?

**EDIT:**

Just read [chaos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178141/what-is-the-problem-with-this-jquery-code/1178189#1178189), which sounds like a plausible explanation.

By the way, element ids must be unique within HTML markup - this is part of the HTML specification and may be another possible explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try giving different names to your submit input elements.

Comment: I'd like to but they are formed in a loop by my script (I only put what I hope is the relevant part of the code up there).

Comment: I am just concerned it might have something to do with successful control definition.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.... Figured out that I was applying the change function in a loop...i.e. my earlier code was....

```
$("table#UserIRTable > tbody > tr").each(function()
{
   ..............
   ..............

  $("input[id='thisMonthSupply']").change(function(e){  
      ......
    });
  ..........
  ..........
}
```

took the change function out and bingo... it worked.....