# How do I check if a key exists in a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, exists

I want to check if parameter `$PGkey` is equal to a key with the same name inside a hash table.  Further, I want to do it in a format as close to this as possible:

```
while(<PARAdef>) {
    my($PGkey, $PGval) = split /\s+=\s+/;
    if($PGkey == $hash{$PGkey}) {
        print PARAnew "$PGkey = $hash{$PGkey}->[$id]\n";
    } else {
        print PARAnew "$PGkey = $PGval\n";
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is your code not working?

Comment: Are you sure "==" is the operator your want there?  Are $PGkey and $hash{$PGkey} both numbers?  If they're strings, use "eq" instead.

Comment: John - yes, they are strings.
Mani - you can see Chas answer, maybe it will light you my solved problem :)

Comment: But only when you are online.

Comment: But decoding the question that the OP didn't ask is the SO advanced game, and really quite entertaining.  I'm very proud of this one, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178141/why-does-my-jquery-click-handler-appear-to-run-multiple-times-for-some-of-its-tar/1178169

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [conditional operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) lets you factor out the common code in that if/else statement:

```
while ( <PARAdef> ) {
    chomp;
    my ($PGkey, $PGval) = split /\s+=\s+/;
    print "$PGkey = ",
        $PGval eq $hash{$PGkey}[$id] ? $hash{$PGkey}[$id] : $PGval, "\n";
}
```

Or if you just misstated the problem and really want to use $hash{$PGkey}[$id] if $hash{$PGkey} exists and fall back to $PGval if it doesn't, then you can say

```
while ( <PARAdef> ) {
    chomp;
    my ($PGkey, $PGval) = split /\s+=\s+/;
    print "$PGkey = ",
        $PGkey ne "def" and exists $hash{$PGkey} ?
            $hash{$PGkey}[$id] : $PGval, "\n";
}
```

A quick note, you seem to be using the old bareword style filehandles.  The new (if ten years old can be considered new) lexical filehandles are superior in every way:

```
open my $PARAdef, "<", $filename
    or die "could not open $filename: $!";
```

Comment: Please, sir, stop calling the conditional operator "the ternary operator".  I beg of you.

Comment: @Manni: Learn what "ternary operator" means, please.  It means an operator that takes three arguments.  `?:` is not the only possible operator that takes three arguments.  What it is legitimately defined by is the fact that it defines a conditional alternation, which is why to call it by its correct name, the conditional operator.

Comment: Thanks Chas, the second answer seems to work fine. Even though it create an empty line between each of the unmatched keys. The file handle I used: open(PARAdef, "<$para_dir/$para_def_file") or die $!;   I'll take your note to my mind - THANKS !

Comment: Can I add to your 2 answer somehow a case that if $PGval == "def" then print PARAdef "$PGkey = $PGval"  ?

Comment: I know what "ternary operator" means. It may well be a very bad name, but it's its name.

Comment: @chaos You have a good point.  I will change it because it will make finding it in perlop easier.  I could have sworn it was named the ternary in ANSI C (which is where I came from initially), but even in "The C Programming Language" it is referred to as the "conditional expresssion".

Comment: @Manni Take a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator, it surprised me as well, but hey, I got my learn-one-new-thing-a-day out of the way early today.

Comment: @YoDar I assumed you wanted that behavior, the reason the blank lines are showing up is $_ is set to the line that was read from PARAdef (including its line-ending-character(s)). Your split does not affect this, so $PGval has a "\n" on its end. The solution is to use chomp to removed the line-ending-character(s) before the split occurs. I have modified the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 16):

The way to check for hash key existence is:

```
exists $hash{$key}
```