# How can I stop a JqueryUI Modal Dialog from being initiated multiple times?

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

Here's the scenario - without code (simpler that way):

1. Load a div with content (including scripts).
2. One of the scripts is the initialization of a JqueryUI Modal dialog - which is "opened" with a click event later in the script... i.e., it's not initialized and opened at the same time.
3. The click event opens this modal that has a form.
4. Upon submitting the form, an ajax call is made - saves data to the database, then causes a ".load" function to reload that entire div -- once again loading that set of scripts (including the initialization of the modal)

THEN...

*[edit]*

**The FIRST time you click to open the modal and form, everything's fine.  Any subsequent time(s) - the form and ajax call are run multiple times.**

*[/edit]*

It seems fairly clear to me that initializing the modal again causes two instances to be called up when the click event fires.

Soo..

Is there a way (since - remember - the div that holds this code is being reloaded -- and yes I've tried placing it outside that div.. no go ) to stop the initialization from happening again?

---

Here's what I tried with regard to using $.one function:

```
$("body").one("load", function(e){
    $("#scheduleMessagePopupDiv").dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       height: 450,
       width: 340,
       modal: true,
       resizeable: false,
       dragable: false
    });
    alert("hello");
});
```

Didn't work.. the alert never fires... and apparently the dialog is never initialized.

Comment: Can you post the **relevant** script/html please? If possible in **addition** a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net to DEMO the current scenario/issue would help a lot too.

Comment: I really wish I could.  But this client is **extremely** hyper-sensitive about this code info getting out.  Really trying to find a way to detect whether a JqueryUI modal has already been initialized.  If I could find that - then I would simply block the loading the next time.

Comment: I think the easiest way around this is to simply embed all the dialog initializations and divs for the dialogs into the housing page - outside the div that gets reloaded.  It seems to be the only true (and probably the proper) way to do this.

Comment: It may have to do with multiple bindings. Try out the solution from my answer. Though it may be to do with how you initialize the dialog. Give it a shot anyway and let me know.

Comment: I deleted my answer, seeing moving the dialogue initialization out fixed the issue and it had nothing to do with multiple bindings after all. Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me that this can be solved by simply using the `$.one()` function http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Gave that a try.. see my edit for what I've tried.  Unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what your problem is: you probably are trying to dynamically add handlers for click event. Look at this post, hopefully you can find something helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178141/why-does-my-jquery-click-handler-appear-to-run-multiple-times-for-some-of-its-ta

Comment: I read that.. and it seems logical - but not the case for me.  But that's great info... thanks!